# instance of template

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

I need to implement template class in following way

Requirement:
you must provide code for implementing a sorting 'comparator' called `SensibleLessThan`, that is capable of sorting text strings.

and it will call in following way.

```
SensibleLessThan<String> comparer;
  String lhs = "Aadvark";
  String rhs = "Zygote";
  comparer(lhs, rhs);
```

Should I write `SensibleLessThan` class and create object? But they are calling comparer like
function. Can anyone provide me some idea how can I accomplish this?

Please let me know if I need to provide more info.

Comment: You might want to look at lexicographical sorting if you don't have that part figured out yet. That would be the one to choose.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Look up the `operator()`. It lets you apply the function call operator on an object.

Comment: you mean I should write conversion operator. So I need to create object and write conversion operator and pass parameter.

Comment: No, not a conversion operator. I mean you should implement a function call operator. It lets you use the object as if it is a function.